# Web Crawl using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I found these functions online that works for the most part, expect for exactly what i need it to do.

I want to store the results of the post_data function in an variable , then use `simple_dom` to take out the things I want.

Instead, the post_data function is loading the entire page and ignoring my `simple_dom` code.

---

#### My code :

```
//include simpleDom
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
 
//Upload a blank cookie.txt to the same directory as this file with a CHMOD/Permission to 777
function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  
 
function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}
 
function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);    
}


login("http://example.com/SecurityPage.php","customerID=1234&password=abc123");

$html = str_get_html(post_data("http://example.com/PlayerGameSelection.php","keyword_search=&inetWagerNumber=0.4349700075546493&inetSportSelection=sport&contestType1=&contestType2=&contestType3=&inetWagerNumber=0.4349700075546493&inetSportSelection=sport&BASKETBALL_NCAA_Game_=on"));

$tables = $html->find('table.teams_betting_options_advanced');
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    echo $table;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `simple_html_dom.php`?

Comment: @thebestusernameever: That would be this library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thats the correct library

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21658797)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the simpleDom portion of the code. If i remove all the simpleDom code and have $html = post_data("xxx"); it will still print out the entire page and I didnt even do a print or echo